# Си очистка stdin

Tags: c

Есть функция, которая принимает на ввод 1 символ:

```
void getChoice( void )
{
    fprintf( stdout, "\n\t?> " );
    choice = getchar();
    clearBuffer();
    return;
}
```

И функция очистки стандартного потока ввода ( stdin ):

```
void clearBuffer( void )
{
    int buffer = 0;

    //Для windows. 
    if ( IN_WINDOWS ) 
    {
        fflush( stdin );
    }
    else
    {
        while ( (buffer = getchar()) != '\n' && buffer != '\n' );
    }

    return;
}
```

Если сидеть не из под винды и нажать `Enter` при вводе, то функция `clearBuffer()` ждет повторного нажатия. Как избежать такого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
if ((choice = getchar()) != '\n') clearBuffer();
```

Встречный вопрос: зачем такая странная конструкция

```
while ( (buffer = getchar()) != '\n' && buffer != '\n' );
```

(имею в виду два сравнения с `'\n'`)?

Comment: На английском stackoverflow парень сказал что так надежней. Думаете ненужно?

Comment: Супер. Спасибо!

Comment: Кстати вариант неплох. Но буфер очищается только когда ввод `'\n'` Я хотел после каждого ввода очищать буффер.

Comment: Уверен. сначала вы проверяете, что `buffer` не равно `\n`? и если не равно, то выполняется вторая часть - проверяется, что `buffer` не равно `\n`. И если таки не равно, цикл повторяется :)

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что именно вы хотите? `getchar()` ждет, пока вы не нажмете Enter. Когда нажали - берет из буфера первый символ. Мой вариант - если просто нажат Enter - ничего не сбрасывать, буфер уже пуст. Если же не `\n` - то в буфере что-то есть.

Comment: А в случаее когда пользователь вводит к премеру вместо одного символа несколько. В `choice` записывается первый символ , а остальные висят в буфере консоли и если я захочу опять сделать ввода, то в него залезет тот мусор из буфера. Я хочу сделать очистку бефера консоли после каждного ввода.

Comment: Блин. А я что вам написал? Вы пробовали запустить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59308/discussion-between-biggy-and-harry).

Comment: Нет, туда я не пойду...